# ansible - need output in csv in multiple columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, ansible

I have playbook as below:

```
 tasks:
       - name: To Get list of all ACM 
         aws_acm_info:
                 region: "{{ region }}"
         register: acm
         
   - name: Cname Names
     set_fact:  
         cname:  "{{ acm | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
     vars:
        jmesquery: 'certificates[*].domain_validation_options[].resource_record.name'
        
   - name: Cname Values
     set_fact:  
         value:  "{{ acm | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
     vars:
        jmesquery: 'certificates[*].domain_validation_options[].resource_record.value'
                         
         
   - name: set file header
     shell: echo 'cname, value'> {{ path }}
     run_once: true
      
           
   - name: CSV - Write information into .csv file
     lineinfile:
         insertafter: ','
         dest: "{{ path }}"
         line: "{{ item }}"
     with_items: 
         - "{{ cname }}" 
         - "{{ value }}"
```

I am getting output in single column as cname, but I need values in 2nd column as value.

required output format world be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXsE5.png)

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you provide the input and values for `cname` and `value`? As well the expected output? Without the data structure answering will become guessing.

Comment: i have edited playbook and my expexted output would be in below CSV format 

'cname Value
ABC     xyz
pqr       lmn'

etc in excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

Given the data below for testing

```yaml
  acm:
    certificates:
    - domain_validation_options:
      - resource_record: {name: aaa, value: 1}
    - domain_validation_options:
      - resource_record: {name: bbb, value: 2}
    - domain_validation_options:
      - resource_record: {name: ccc, value: 3}
```

Get the name/value pairs in a single query

```yaml
    _query: 'certificates[*].domain_validation_options[].[resource_record.name,
                                                          resource_record.value]'
    csv: "{{ acm|json_query(_query)|map('join', ',')|list }}"
```

give

```yaml
  csv:
  - aaa,1
  - bbb,2
  - ccc,3
```

You can write the lines into a file

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/cname.csv
        line: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ csv }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/cname.csv 
aaa,1
bbb,2
ccc,3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    acm:
      certificates:
      - domain_validation_options:
        - resource_record: {name: aaa, value: 1}
      - domain_validation_options:
        - resource_record: {name: bbb, value: 2}
      - domain_validation_options:
        - resource_record: {name: ccc, value: 3}
    _query: 'certificates[*].domain_validation_options[].[resource_record.name,
                                                          resource_record.value]'
    csv: "{{ acm|json_query(_query)|map('join', ',')|list }}"
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/cname.csv
        line: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ csv }}"
```

Read the file

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - community.general.read_csv:
        path: /tmp/cname.csv
        fieldnames: cname,value
        delimiter: ','
      register: cname
    - debug:
        var: cname.list
```

gives

```yaml
  cname.list:
    - {cname: aaa, value: '1'}
    - {cname: bbb, value: '2'}
    - {cname: ccc, value: '3'}
```

You can see that the values are strings now. If you want to keep values as integers store the data in YAML format

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    acm:
      certificates:
      - domain_validation_options:
        - resource_record: {name: aaa, value: 1}
      - domain_validation_options:
        - resource_record: {name: bbb, value: 2}
      - domain_validation_options:
        - resource_record: {name: ccc, value: 3}
    _query: 'certificates[*].domain_validation_options[].[resource_record.name,
                                                          resource_record.value]'
    csv: "{{ acm|json_query(_query)|map('join', ': ')|list }}"
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/cname.yml
        line: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ csv }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/cname.yml
aaa: 1
bbb: 2
ccc: 3
```

Read the file

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: /tmp/cname.yml
        name: cname_dict
    - debug:
        var: cname_dict
```

gives

```yaml
  cname_dict:
    aaa: 1
    bbb: 2
    ccc: 3
```